# index.js command handler problems

Tags: command, handler

I have a problem, when I debug on visual studio code, it gives me this error message "Uncaught Error: Cannot find module './command/$(files)'
Require stack:
"c:\Users\user\OneDrive\Bureau\himetsubabot\index.js"

however I put the right path and my file is called commande, here is the code

```
const fs = require('fs');
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const bot = new Discord.Client()
const config = require ("./config.js");

bot.commands = new Discord.Collection();
const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commande').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

for (const file of commandFiles) {
    const command = require('./commande/$(files)')
    client.command.set(command.name, command)
}

bot.on("ready", async message => {
    console.log("Le bot démarre")
    bot.user.setStatus('online')
    bot.user.setActivity("en développement")

})

bot.on('message', async (msg) => {
    if(msg.content.startsWith(config.prefix) && !msg.author.bot){
        cmdArray = msg.content.substring(config.prefix.length).split(" ");
        cmd = cmdArray[0];
        args = cmdArray.slice(1);

        let command = commands.getCommand(cmd);
        if(command) command.run(bot, msg, args);

        if(cmd === '8ball'){}
    }
})
bot.login(config.token)
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `"('/commande/$(files)')"` use `"('./commande/${files}')"`.

What i mean is to use `${files}` instead of `$(files)`.